# setInterval() Not being cleared?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to use the page visibility api to pause a canvas animation when the user switches focus to another browser tab:

```
var hidden, visibilityChange; 
if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") { // Opera 12.10 & Firefox 18 & later support
  hidden = "hidden";
  visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
} 

function drawStuff () {
  //draws & rotates stuff on canvas
}
function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (document[hidden]) {
    clearInterval(drawPic);
  } else {
    var drawPic = setInterval(drawStuff, 60);
  }
}

handleVisibilityChange();
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
```

I'd like the animation to resume exactly where it left off, but for some reason every time I leave the tab and come back to my page, the setInterval doesn't clear and the drawing speeds up as if there were multiple setIntervals being called on it. If you leave and come back to the tab multiple times, the animation speeds up to absurd proportions.

What's going on here? Why isn't the interval being cleared in the handleVisibilityChange function?

Edit: Moving the var declaration fixed it, thanks.

Edit 2: Added in the code of document[hidden] for future reference (as mentioned by Suing & Tushar).

Comment: Declare `var drawPic;` outside of the function. and remove `var` from the `else`. Assuming `document[hidden]` is correct.

Comment: This is because `drawPic` is a local variable and when you try to clear it, it returns undefined

Comment: Try `document['hidden']`

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**
In lew of comments.

I made a mistake and `requestAnimationFrame` will not keep the computer awake by itself. It will though if you are playing video and you can use `requestAnimationFrame` to view the video. Though it is the video that keeps the computer awake.

Also the term "*focus*" may not be correct, though it was suggested that it only updates when "*visible*" is not accurate as it keeps firing when you place another window over the window, event if that window is maximised, or scroll what you are animating out of view. Nor does `requestAnimationFrame` have to display anything, and the call is unaware of what you do in the body of the callback, you may just be counting frames.

For now I will use the term "*page focus*", meaning that the page is the displayed tab of the browser window, it does not have to have system focus to fire, though if someone has a more accurate description do say.

Use `window.requestAnimationFrame(functionName);`  it stops calling when you lose page focus and then starts again when you regain page focus. Provides  the max visible frame rate the browser supports (1/60th of a second interval) an syncs animations with the browser's layout and renderer.

See [MDN requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for details on how to use and compatibility.

Comment: and it even have a *slightly* better support than Page Visibility API

Comment: You are right that the effect of using `requestAnimationFrame` should be the same as if you where listing to the `visibilitychange` event. But the term `focus` is misleading, because it is about visibility and not about focus. The `requestAnimationFrame` will also be called when the windows does not have the focus but its content is visible and might not be called when it has the focus but the content of the window is not visible anymore. And are you sure about the `[...]It also keeps the device awake[...]` is this defined somewhere? (My device went asleep)

Comment: @t.niese I will remove focus and replace visible once I have confirmed it. Keeping the device alive I know from experience. When I have an app open (visible) that uses it my machines do not sleep. I use Chrome but I can not be sure if that is true for other implementations or if it is part of the standard or just something added by the browser creators. Will check and update if requiered.

Comment: I tried it here on two devices and two different browsers and having an active `requestAnimationFrame` did not keep any of  them awake, so either it is device/ browser/os dependent or you have something in your callback that will have this result. I also don't see anything in the specs that indicates that this should keep a device awake.

Comment: @t.niese, anyway, because of the lot of advantages that rAF has over setInterval, you should not use setInterval to do animations anymore. You can also use cancelAnimationFrame() + visibility API.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
move the "var drawPic;" declaration outside of the function.  Other code included (for completeness sake) if someone else needs to test in the future.

```
// Set the name of the hidden property and the change event for visibility
var hidden, visibilityChange; 
if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") { // Opera 12.10 and Firefox 18 and later support 
  hidden = "hidden";
  visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.mozHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "mozHidden";
  visibilityChange = "mozvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "msHidden";
  visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "webkitHidden";
  visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
}

function drawStuff () {
  //draws & rotates stuff on canvas
}

var drawPic;

function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (document[hidden]) {
    clearInterval(drawPic);
  } else {
    drawPic = setInterval(drawStuff, 60);
  }
}

handleVisibilityChange();

// Warn if the browser doesn't support addEventListener or the Page Visibility API
if (typeof document.addEventListener === "undefined" || 
  typeof document[hidden] === "undefined") {
  alert("This demo requires a browser, such as Google Chrome or Firefox, that supports the Page Visibility API.");
} else {
  // Handle page visibility change   
  document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);

}
```

Comment: You should explain what you  changed to get it work. You added so much code, that is only necessary to target older browsers  and the important part is not easy to see because of that.

Comment: t.niese, your comment has been acknowledged.